# difference between Groovy JDK API Documentation and groovy api Documentation

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy I want to know the exact difference between Groovy JDK API Documentation and groovy api Documentation. I want to know the purpose of those api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy adds additional methods to some JDK library classes (e.g String, File). These additional methods are known as the Groovy JDK and are [documented here](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/). All the methods that are available when using JDK classes in a Java program are also available when using them from a Groovy program.

Comment: Ok thank you then What is the purpose of Groovy api is it same as Groovy JDK